# ZeroClipboard - copy to clipboard issue.

Tags: javascript, jquery, zeroclipboard

I was wondering why it does everything , just not the actual text copy on

> that line : client.on('dataRequested', function(client, args) {

```
$("body").on("click","#bonus-copy",function(){

    var _globalConfig = {

      swfPath: "js/ZeroClipboard.swf",
      trustedDomains: [window.location.host],
      cacheBust: true,
      forceHandCursor: false,
      zIndex: 999999999,
      debug: false,
      title: null,
      autoActivate: true,
      hoverClass: "zeroclipboard-is-hover",
      activeClass: "zeroclipboard-is-active",
      trustedOrigins: null,
      allowScriptAccess: null,
      useNoCache: true,
      moviePath: "ZeroClipboard.swf"
    };

    var client = new ZeroClipboard();


    client.on('dataRequested', function(client, args) {
        var text = document.getElementById('copy-text').value;
        var windowsText = text.replace(/\n/g, '\r\n');
        client.setText(windowsText);
        alert(windowsText);
    });


});
```

Comment: Why are you setting global variables on every click

Answer (score 0):

You need to start and configure the ZeroClipboard before clicking on the button.